# cv2.getTrackbarPos() throws (-27:Null pointer) NULL window in function 'cvGetTrackbarPos'

Tags: python, opencv

Currently using Python 3.9.13, OpenCV 4.6.0. The problem is that I can't use "cv2.getTrackbarPos()" on my Windows 10 laptop. However, the code works fine on my Raspberry Pi 0 2w. Tried on both Python IDLE Shell and Visual Studio, same error messages.

Code:

```py
import cv2

winName = "colors"

def nothing(x):
    pass

img_original = cv2.imread("capture.png")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.namedWindow("colors")

cv2.createTrackbar('LowerbH', "colors", 55, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('LowerbS', "colors", 65, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('LowerbV', "colors", 55, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('UpperbH', "colors", 85, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('UpperbS', "colors", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('UpperbV', "colors", 255, 255, nothing)

while(1):
    lowerbH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LowerbH', "colors")
    lowerbS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LowerbS', "colors")
    lowerbV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LowerbV', "colors")
    upperbH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('UpperbH', "colors")
    upperbS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('UpperbS', "colors")
    upperbV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('UpperbV', "colors")
    
    img_target = cv2.inRange(img_original, (lowerbH, lowerbS, lowerbV), (upperbH, upperbS, upperbV))
    
    img_specifiedColor = cv2.bitwise_and(img_original, img_original, mask = img_target)
    cv2.imshow(winName, img_specifiedColor)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Color-Optimize.py", line 34, in <module>
    lowerbH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LowerbH', "colors")
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:2581: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window: 'colors' in function 'cvGetTrackbarPos'
```

Comment: in python, indentation is syntax. it has meaning. you destroyed all windows *inside your loop*, which causes the error. move that call to outside of the loop. -- voting to close as a **typo**, because this needs one level of indentation removed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that, can you explain more about it? Does it mean the problem is indentation?

Comment: If the problem is indentation, then why can my Raspberry pi run the code perfectly?

Comment: ok, I think I should retract the close vote. this could happen to others (a window not existing when you thought it did), but due to other causes. -- that's because, *either* the GUI code in OpenCV for linux does something different (low chance of that), *or* you *did not* run the same code. you probably mix tabs and spaces, or made an error in copying the code.

Comment: OHHHHHHH, I see! I retyped those indentations with tabs again and it works fine!!!!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (admittedly cryptic) error says that the window `"colors"` no longer exists.

Why? Because you called `cv.destroyAllWindows()` **in your loop**. That closes all created windows.

Don't do that. Call it once, **after** and outside of the loop.

Comment: Seems there's a problem when I copied the codes onto the website, cuz on my code editor, there's no indentations on `cv.destroyAllWindows()`

Answer (score 0):

I had to admit that I was really stupid. First, I called `cv.destroyAllWindows()` **inside** the loop, very embarrassing. Second, **the tabs**. As I retyped all the indentations of the block, it works perfectly.